# custom control in blackberry using jde

Tags: blackberry-jde

I want to make custom control which consists of a LabelField and Textbox.
How can i make a custom control using jde as IDE for blackberry.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In Blackberry you can create a custom component by extending from Field

```
  public class MyField extends Field {
       public void layout(int width, int height){
            setExtent( width, height ); //set the field size
       }
       public void pain(Graphics g){
          //do your own paint here
          //g.drawText ("Test", 0, 0 );
       }
  }
```

in case you want to create consist of a LabelField and TextField, I suggest you extend from TextField

```
  public class InputField extends TextField {
       private String _label;
       private TextField _text;
       public InputField(String label){
          _label = label;
       }

       public void layout(int width, int height ){
           setExtend( width + 200, height ); //just an example, i add 200 pixel for width
           //you can get the width of the _label too
           //need other functions to get width based on the String
       }          

       //you override how to paint in screen
       public void paint(Graphics g){
            super.paint(g);
            g.drawText (getLeft()-200, getTop(), _label);                            
       }
  }
```

See more examples here
http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Custom-Control/td-p/159699